# Node js mysql returns empty result when asking with AND operator

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have trouble with MySQL query in Node.js

This is my source code:

```
var passwordHash = sha512(data.passwordLogin).toString('hex');

database.query('SELECT `name`, `email`, `email-validated` FROM Players WHERE `email` = ? AND `password` = ?', [database.escape(data.name), database.escape(passwordHash)], function (error, results, fields) {
    if(error)
        logger.error(error); 
    else
    {
        logger.debug(results[0].name); //This line returns an empty array
    }
});
```

It is working fine when I ask only for email, but with AND operator in query it returns an empty array as result.

Data given to query and data in database are equal.

Also trying to access something like `results[0]`, `results[0][0]` or `results[0].name` causes server (app.js) to crash.

Any ideas to solve this? If you need more information about the source code just ask.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you verified that a row with those two values for email and password actually exists?

Comment: You don't need to escape when using placeholders. Also, can you log `results` (or do you mean that logging `results` returns an empty array?).